# SCSS: using my own custom frameworks - File path and including webfonts

Tags: sass

I have created my own set of custom SCSS frameworks that I want to use between projects.

[This](http://vimeo.com/13804978) video shows how to do this. However, I am having some problems:

1) The Path to your custom SCSS framework has to be absolute
According to the video, the path to your frame work must be absolute (e.g. load "/Users/USERNAME/ frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK"). Is there a way to make this relative, so if I change machines the framework reference will still be correct?

2) In my custom framework, I have included some webfonts. When the stylesheet is complied, the paths to these fonts is wrong. Is there a way to make the fonts included in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used Codekit for this: http://incident57.com/codekit/

It's really easy. Just have a folder on a computer that contains your framework and then set it as a Codekit framework.

You can then use the import command from any SCSS file to import files from the framework.

You can even have a javascript/jquery file framework.

This is easily the best tool for Web Development. I can't imagine development without it.